# Using keras tokenizer on Spark DataFrame. Column is not iterable

Tags: python, keras, pyspark

I am having trouble using the Tokenizer

The code is

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df.descricao_despesa)



X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df.descricao_despesa)


maxlen = 100

X= pad_sequences(df.descricao_despesa, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
```

I tried to cast column descricao_despesa to String but still doest work.

If i try to cast to StringType i receive

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = df.withColumn("descricao_despesa", col("descricao_despesa").cast('StringType'))

ParseException: u'\nDataType stringtype() is not supported.(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nStringType\n^^^\n
```

I am using spark 2.0 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that one can use Keras on Spark to process data *in parallel (using multiple workers)*.

But if your data can fit in RAM on a single node, that you can easily create a Pandas DataFrame from a Spark DataFrame and pass that DF to Keras. You can also convert result back to Spark DF if you need.

Spark DF --> Pandas DF:

```
pdf = df.toPandas() # df - is a Spark DataFrame
```

Pandas DF --> Spark DF:

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```